# R: Can the entries of a data frame be vectors of length > 1?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

Is it possible for the entries of a data frame to be vectors of length > 1? For example, I tried the following:

```
A <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2))
A[1,1] <- list("a","b")
```

But I got the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, 1, value = list("a", "b")) :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

The result was that A[1,1] was assigned the value "a" rather than ("a","b"). Is there a way to make this work? Or do I need to use a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible but you need to convert the column to a list. Here is a raw example:

```
A[[1]] <- vector(mode="list", length=2L)
A[[c(1,1)]] <- list("a","b") 
A

    X1 X2
1 a, b NA
2 NULL NA
```